# Xcode 4 won't recognize that framework headers directory is committed (GIT)

Tags: xcode, git

I copied the Parse.com framework to my project and committed everything fine, but for some reason the Headers directory will not lose the `A` status which prevents me from pushing my changes to my remote repository. I circumvented this using the terminal and git in the terminal considers this directory already committed but for some reason Xcode continues to thing it needs to be committed even after I've tried a few times. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: File a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com)? It sounds like there might be a bug with version control status of folder references (which this is, as opposed to groups, which is what 99% of "folders" in Xcode really are).

Comment: Filed a bug report, hoping someone knows a work around for now.

Comment: Have you tried asking Xcode to Refresh Status (see File->Source Control->Refresh Status)?

Comment: I assume you've already tried rebooting Xcode. As a last-ditch effort, you could close the project, open the Organizer, go to the Projects tab, delete your project from there (this deletes all the DerivedData for the project), then quit and relaunch Xcode and reopen your project. This should clear out all metadata Xcode has about your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and to fix it I had to go into the terminal and commit my changes manually. That fixed the problem. But it was kind of annoying. Not sure if I'll have to do that every time at this stage.